# ReferenceError: getMessage not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am building a messaging area similar to facebook and I am using ajax with jquery and a asmx web service to serve the html to the client. My li click event works when the content is first loaded on page load using c#, but when ajax runs and refreshes the content from the web service the li event doesn't work anymore.

This an example of the html that is returned from the web service

```
<ol class="messagesrow" id="messages">
<li id="2345">
<div>Test Element</div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Web service markup

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetMessagesByObject(string id, string objectid, string userid, string timezone)
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        DataSet results = results from store procedure

        str.Append("<ol class=\"messagesrow\" id=\"messages\">");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = results.Tables[0].Rows[i];

            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreateDate"].ToString()).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(timezone));

            if (!TDG.Common.CheckStringForEmpty(row["ParentMessageID"].ToString()))
            {
                str.Append("<li id=\"" + row["ParentMessageID"].ToString() + "\">");
            }
            else
            {
                str.Append("<li id=\"" + row["MessageID"].ToString() + "\">");
            }

            str.Append("<div style=\"width:100%; cursor:pointer;\">");

            str.Append("<div style=\"float:left; width:25%;\">");
            if (!TDG.Common.CheckStringForEmpty(row["ImageID"].ToString()))
            {
                str.Append("<img src=\"/Resources/getThumbnailImage.ashx?w=48&h=48&id=" + row["ImageID"].ToString() + "\" alt=\"View Profile\" />");
            }
            else
            {
                str.Append("<img src=\"/images/noProfileImage.gif\" alt=\"View Profile\" />");
            }
            str.Append("</div>");

            str.Append("<div style=\"float:left; width:75%; padding-top:4px;\">");
            str.Append("<strong>" + row["WholeName"].ToString() + "</strong>");
            str.Append("<br />");
            if (row["BodyMessage"].ToString().Length < 35)
            {
                str.Append("<span class=\"smallText\">" + row["BodyMessage"].ToString() + "</span>");
            }
            else
            {
                str.Append("<span class=\"smallText\">" + row["BodyMessage"].ToString().Substring(0, 35) + "</span>");
            }
            str.Append("<br /><span class=\"smallGreyText\">" + String.Format("{0:g}", date) + "</span>");
            str.Append("</div>");

            str.Append("</div>");
            str.Append("</li>");
        }
        str.Append("</ol>");

        output = str.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Jquery markup

```
$(document).ready(function () {        

    $("ol#messages li").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        getMessage(id);
    });
});

function getMessage(id) {

        var timezone = $('#<%= hdfTimezone.ClientID %>').val()
        var userid = $('#<%= hdfUserID.ClientID %>').val()

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Resources/MessageWebService.asmx/GetMessage",
            data: "{'id':'" + id + "','timezone':'" + timezone + "','userid':'" + userid + "' }",
            success: function (data) { 
                $('#<%= hdfMessageID.ClientID %>').val(id);
                $('#<%= ltlMessages.ClientID %>').html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showError(data.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Did you try debugging the Javascript in the browser in order to find the point of failure?

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't make sense, however the event stops getting triggered because the new elements don't have the event bound to them. You should use event delegation here with the .on method.

Comment: This seems like the right answer, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: kevin, I tried the .on method but its telling me that its not a function. Im using jquery version 1.6.4 from googleapis library

Comment: @chadn then you want the .delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your list items are dynamic, you should delegate the event from the ol.

```
$(document).ready(function () {        

    $("#messages").delegate("li","click",function () {
        getMessage(this.id);
    });

});
```

The error you are getting `ReferenceError: getMessage not defined` shouldn't happen with the given code.